# Wire wound inductors naming

Tags: inductor, surface-mount

I see some SMT wire wound inductors are named like 3R3 or 4R5, much like a resistor, why so? I expected them to be like 4H5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "R" in the value doesn't stand for "resistance", it stands for ["radix point"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point). This makes the designation language-/localization-independent, since different regions use different symbols for the radix point, e.g. ".", ",", etc.

Comment: That's one I would have never figured out haha I was thinking about something related to impedance, but not this