# What does 0.025R or 30R mean here?

Tags: resistors

On a schematic I have, some resistors read as **R16, 0.025R, 3W**. Some read as **R60, 33R**. I guessed that R16 or R60 are the labels, and 3W is the power. But what does **0.025R** or **30R** mean? Google search did not help much. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90699/wire-wound-inductors-naming

Comment: So many possible duplicates: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246920/what-is-a-100r-resistor

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45272/resistor-value-labeling-what-does-the-second-number-refer-to 
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107698/what-does-5k1-in-the-given-schematic-mean 
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28053/what-does-3v3-or-1v8-mean

Answer (score 8):

In this context "R" means \$\Omega\$.

It really just substitutes for the decimal point and tells you the multiplier. You'll also see inductors marked 1R0 for 1.0\$\mu\$H, and resistances given as 4K7 or 10K0 for 4700\$\Omega\$ and 10,000 \$\Omega\$.

So the resistor with ID R16 is a 0.025 Ohm resistor and the resistor with ID R60 is a 33 Ohm resistor.

Comment: Some other resistors read as **33K**. Are they 33 kOhms?

Comment: Yes, they are 33K ohms.

Comment: @Chu If it starts with "R" in this context, that is the reference designator. This is generally why the value of the resistors don't contain "R"s.

Comment: R60 is 33 ohms, yes?

Comment: @EMFields Yes, thanks, some weird editing there- no doubt my fault.

Comment: Different manufacturers = different methods. The K, M or R can be the decimal point.  33K = 33KΩ, 4K7 = 4.7kΩ.  Surface mount 472 = 4.7kΩ or 4701 = 4.7kΩ at a higher precision.